# Searching for near matching elements of list

Tags: python

I have lists like this:

```
boo = ['<a>', '<b>', '<c>', '</c>', '</b>', '</a>']
```

I'm trying to iterate over them and find matching indexes like `'<c>'`, `'</c>'` and remove those pieces. They have to be next to each other and matching in order to be removed. After the indices are removed, it iterates over the list again and keeps removing until the list is empty or until it cannot anymore.

I'm thinking something like:

```
  for i in range(len(boo)): 
    for b in boo:
       if  boo[i]== '</'+ b +'>' and boo[i-1] == '<' + b +'>':
         boo.remove(boo[i])
         boo.remove(boo[i-1])
         print(boo)
```

but that doesn't appear to be doing anything. Can someone point me to my problem?

**EDIT**

I changed it to more like this, but it is saying i is not defined. How is what I have not defining i?

```
def valid_html1(test_strings):
    valid = []
    for h in test_strings:
      boo = re.findall('\W+\w+\W', h)
      while i in boo == boo[i]:
         if boo[i][1:] == boo[i+1][2:]:
             boo.remove(boo[i])
             boo.remove(boo[i+1])
             print(boo)

valid_html1(example_set)
```

Comment: You're iterating over the same container that you are modifying. That is a really easy way to write complicated code filled with bugs.

Comment: Besides the problem mentioned by Mateen I see that the tags you are comparing in the `if` statement will never match. The `b` variable is already a tag like `<c>` and you are adding `<` and `>` to it again. You need to extract the name from the tag first

Comment: @SantiagoBruno so should there be a like between the for statement and the if statement that takes out the middle? like if b[1:-2] == b[2:-2]? Sorry if that looks completely stupid...I'm pretty new to this

Comment: added an edit to the original

Comment: you had 4 people with different answers, 2 of which had explanations on recommendations of what to do, only one of them uses regex, all of them but one figured out what you wanted to do & already given working solutions, after half a day later you _added a piece of non working code_ to your question?

Comment: Just trying to learn. Thanks @cryptonome.

Answer (score 1):

You should parse the strings to extract the tag names from the angle brackets before you make comparisons. You can use `zip` to pair adjacent tags, and keep appending items to a new list only if its adjacent item is not of the same name:

```
boo = ['<a>', '<b>', '<c>', '</c>', '</b>', '</a>']
while True:
    pairs = zip(boo, boo[1:] + [''])
    new_boo = []
    for a, b in pairs:
        if a.startswith('<') and a.endswith('>') and \
                b.startswith('</') and b.endswith('>') and a[1:-1] == b[2:-1]:
            next(pairs)
            boo = new_boo
            boo.extend(a for a, _ in pairs)
            break
        new_boo.append(a)
    else:
        break
print(boo)
```

This outputs:

```
[]
```

And if `boo = ['<a>', '<b>', '<c>', '</c>', '</b>', '</a>', '<d>']`, this outputs:

```
['<d>']
```

Comment: Interestingly enough, I assumed the desired output here would be `['<a>', '<b>', '</b>', '</a>', '<d>']` but this interpretation probably makes more sense.

Comment: Yes, as the OP says, "After the indices are removed, it iterates over the list again and keeps removing until the list is empty or until it cannot anymore." So we need to keep stripping matching adjacent tags from the new list until there are no more matching adjacent tags.

Answer (score 0):

In 99% of the cases you shouldn't be editing a list while iterating.

This solution makes a copy and then edits the original list:

```
boo_copy = boo[:]
for i, b in enumerate(boo_copy)
   if i == 0:
      continue

   stripped_tag = b.replace("</","").replace(">","").replace("<","") # Removes first and last char to remove '<' and '>'
   if  boo[i]== '</'+ stripped_tag +'>' and boo[i-1] == '<' + stripped_tag +'>':
      boo.remove(boo[i])
      boo.remove(boo[i-1])
      print(boo)
```

This assumes that the tags are unique in the list.

Comment: What is the 1% when you shouldn’t?

Comment: Sorry, meant `shouldn't`

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

def open_tag_as_str(tag):
    m = re.match(r'^<(\w+)>$', tag)
    return None if m is None else m.group(1)

def close_tag_as_str(tag):
    m = re.match(r'^</(\w+)>$', tag)
    return None if m is None else m.group(1)

def remove_adjacent_tags(tags):
    def closes(a, b):
        a = open_tag_as_str(a)
        b = close_tag_as_str(b)
        return a is not None and b is not None and a == b

    # This is a bit ugly and could probably be improved with
    # some itertools magic or something
    skip = False
    for i in range(len(tags)):
        if skip:
            skip = False
        elif i + 1 < len(tags) and closes(tags[i], tags[i + 1]):
            skip = True
        else:
            yield tags[i]

boo = ['<a>', '<b>', '<c>', '</c>', '</b>', '</a>']
boo = list(remove_adjacent_tags(boo))
print(boo)
```

Gives:

```
['<a>', '<b>', '</b>', '</a>']
```